# OCUnit Test Case Issue

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am working OCUnit Test case

```
- (NSDictionary*)Event:(EventBase*)event
{
    [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];
    return nil;
}
```

I found this method to write the test case

In my Test Case Class i pass the event value valid,invalid and nil for the above method

```
-(void)testEventNil{

NSDictionary *t_Dict;
EventClass *t_EventClass = [[EventClass alloc]init];
t_Dict = [t_EventClass Event:nil];
STAssertNil (t_Dict, @"Return nil");
} 

-(void)testEventNil{

NSDictionary *t_Dict;
NSMutableDictionary *invalid;
[invalid setObject:@"1324" forKey @"Number"];
EventClass *t_EventClass = [[EventClass alloc]init];
t_Dict = [t_EventClass Event:];
STAssertNil (t_Dict, @"Return nil");
} 

-(void)testEventvalid{

NSDictionary *t_Dict;
NSMutableDictionary *invalid;
[invalid setObject:@"WorkNameEvent" forKey @"EventNameKey"];
EventClass *t_EventClass = [[EventClass alloc]init];
t_Dict = [t_EventClass Event:];
STAssertNotNil (t_Dict, @"Return nil");
}
```

Its gives me error unrecognized selector sent to instance

Can any one advice me for fixing the issue

@All 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has multiple errors. I can't make sense of it.

You are trying to test a method that is designed to throw an error. Maybe it is intended to be overriden? The only possible test as it is now is

```
EventClass *event = [EventClass new];
STAssertThrows([t_EventClass Event:nil],@"Should throw an error.");
```

When you write: `t_Dict = [t_EventClass Event:];` you are not passing any parameter to the `Event:` method.

This doesn't work either:

```
NSMutableDictionary *invalid;
[invalid setObject:@"WorkNameEvent" forKey @"EventNameKey"];
```

because you didn't initialize the dictionary. That is,

```
NSMutableDictionary *invalid = [NSMutableDictionary new];
```

The convention in Objective-C is to name methods and variables using camel case, in this case `event:` instead `Event:`, and `dic` instead `t_Dic`.

Comment: thats a lot and also for the convention rules for objective C